# Getting DNS resolution error on places.sit.ls.hereapi.com during the weekends only

Tags: here-api

We are getting DNS resolution error on places.sit.ls.hereapi.com during the weekends only. During the week days it is fine. Does anyone else have issues with the here-api places service during the weekends?

Made an api call to places.sit.ls.hereapi.com during the weekend
Expected the call to resolved correctly
Result was "Error resolving DNS name places.sit.ls.hereapi.com"

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the "sit" from the URL, that should work.

```
places.sit.ls.hereapi.com
```

Should be

```
places.ls.hereapi.com
```

Also, if you have DNS issues please try other DNSs on your end if it keeps failing.